# What am I doing wrong with metal detector coil?

Tags: coil, magnetic-flux, detector, metal

I saw on the internet a lot of people making metal detectors so I was thinking of building my own.

I took 35 turns of 0.5 mm wire over a 20 cm diameter air core, connected it to a function generator (-/+10 V, DC 10%, 1 kHz, tr/tf 10 ns).

I tried getting the resonance frequency with a high-end oscilloscope. It was about 3.5 MHz, and had a very ugly waveform. I verified the resonance with a sine wave over the 3.5 MHz.

I tried to move some metal objects, but there was no change in the waveform for small objects and I only got a little change with a large 30*30 cm steel plate at a distance of less then 5 cm.

So I tried to use an RX coil and create a double-D configuration - it was super sensitive at one time (changing the amplitude and phase over my bare hand), and at other times reacted only to the large steel plate at a very short distance; I couldn't say what I did differently though.

I thought maybe the magnetic flux density is low with large coils like 20 cm diameter so I made two 10 cm diameter coils with 70 turns each reusing the same wire, thinking this would increase sensitivity, but it didn't help.

Also tried playing with the polarity - also didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just FYI, steel is pretty much _terrible_ magnetically at MHz levels.  It's easy to think of steel/iron as being magnetic -- everybody knows this.  But seeing steel attract a magnet comes with the caveat that this happens at essentially D.C.  Steel's ferromagnetism decreases _rapidly_ with frequency.  Heck, even 50Hz transformers are noticeably more bulky than equivalent 60Hz versions.  At 3.5 MHz steel is virtually invisible magnetically.

Comment: Ron, are we done with this question now? Did my answer clarify things?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to make it resonate at the coil's self-resonant frequency (due to the coil's parasitic capacitance). This is not a good idea. You should parallel tune the coil starting at about 10 nF and building up capacitance until you have it operating at a much lower frequency that is suitable for beach-combing applications. Use decent ceramic capacitors and a dielectric quality of X7R (at worst) and NP0 at best.

Get your transmit coil working first and get it working at the right frequency i.e. mid audio frequencies and probably not much higher than 10 kHz.

When using your signal generator, use a sinewave excitation to check for resonance because using a square wave can give false readings due to harmonic distortions.